# How many images are generated by keras fit_generator?

Tags: keras, data-augmentation

I use keras to do image augmentation and segmentation. I want to investigate the number of images generated, so I test the following setting of arguments:
(1) set batch_size as 1 in flow_from_directory when define the generator:

```
def myGene(...):
    ...
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(...,batch_size = 1,..., save_prefix  = 'view',...)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**aug_dict)
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(...,batch_size = 1,..., save_prefix  = 'view',...)
    ...
```

(2) When training, I set epochs = 1 and steps_per_epoch=1:

```
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=1,epochs=1,...)
```

After training finished, I expect only 1 image and 1 mask are in the directory './view', but I actually found 11 pairs there.

What is wrong here? Did I fail to setting some arguments, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `fit_generator`, there is a hidden argument called `max_queue_size=10`, which means the generator will try to produce a queue of 10 batches ahead of the current training batch.

You're just seeing the images generated to populate the queue. You can try to use `max_queue_size=0`, but even though you might see an extra image.